# ETL From Sql Server bak file to Postgres or other open source solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, postgresql, data-warehouse

Is there anyway to get table definitions and data from a Sql Server bak file to an open source solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not supported out of the box.  Why not restore the database backup to another server and script out the tables that you need?

If you really need to work with the backups as a database, there is only one product left on the market from [Apex Software](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_restore.aspx).

Red Gate used to have a product called virtual restore but it was discontinued a year ago.

Comment: Main problem was I didn't have a windows box available or a SQL Server instance - ended up loading the image into a Azure instance and trying to fiddle with that. Never thought to try and script out the tables I needed since it was a hackathon and for some reason I thought that would take too long.